# Marshall JSON Slice to valid JSON

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I'm building a REST API using Golang but I'm having some troubles trying to correctly Marshalling a Json Slice. I've been scratching my head for a while now, even after looking to several questions and answer and on the web.

Essentially, I have a **Redis** client that called after a call `-X GET /todo/` spits up a slice of `todos`

```
[{"content":"test6","id":"46"} {"content":"test5","id":"45"}] //[]string
```

Now, I want to return a given `Response` based on the fact that I found `todos` or not, so I have a `Struct` like

```
type Response struct {
    Status string
    Data []string
}
```

Then, If I found some `todos` I just `Marshal` a json with

```
if(len(todos) > 0){
    res := SliceResponse{"Ok", todos}
    response, _ = json.Marshal(res)
}
```

And, In order to remove unnecessary `\` inside the response, I use `bytes.Replace` like

```
response = bytes.Replace(response, []byte("\\"), []byte(""), -1)
```

Finally, getting

```
{
   "Status" : "Ok",
   "Data" : [
              "{"content":"test6","id":"46"}",
              "{"content":"test5","id":"45"}"
    ]
}
```

As you can see each `"` before each `{` and after each `}`, excluding the first and the last ones, are clearly wrong.
While the correct JSON would be

```
{
    "Status": "Ok",
    "Data": [{
        "content ": "test6",
        "id ": "46"
    }, {
        "content ": "test5",
        "id ": "45"
    }]
}
```

> I successfully managed to get them off by finding their index and trim them off and
>   also with regex but I was wondering.

**Is there a clean and better way to achieve that?**

Comment: Why are you leaving the redis response as strings, and not some more concrete type? Your data model has those rows as strings, so of course it has to escape the quotes to put those in json. If your json code involves string processing, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Using [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) and `todos, _ := c.LRange("todos", 0, -1).Result()` returns a `[]string`.

Comment: You could parse each item to a struct type perhaps. Checking an alternate solution now.

Comment: Well, I have a `Todo` struct with `id` and `content` and I already tried that solution but, I got the same result. Should I show that also?

Comment: If Response.Data is a `[]*Todo`, and you can get it into that form, it should marshal just fine. Using `json.RawMessage` instead of string is another possibility, but also requires some extra processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever possible you should marshal from go objects that match your desired json. I'd recommend parsing the json from redis:

```
type Response struct {
    Status string
    Data   []*Info
}

type Info struct {
    Content string `json:"content"`
    ID      string `json:"id"`
}

func main() {
    r := &Response{Status: "OK"}
    for _, d := range data {
        info := &Info{}
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(d), info)
        //handle error
        r.Data = append(r.Data, info)
    }
    dat, _ := json.Marshal(r)
    fmt.Println(string(dat))
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/ourp0B2GWi)